# What's the meaning of $x \choose y$ in the Catalan number formula?

Tags: notation

What's the meaning of $\choose$ in [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):

$$C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}\qquad\mathrm{for}\;n\geq 0$$

Is it a division?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation $n\choose r$ means "the number of ways of choosing $r$ things out of a total of $n$ given things, where order is not important."  Its value is $n!/r!(n-r)!$.

For example, given five coins, say a penny, a nickel, a dime, a quarter, and a dollar, there are 10 ways to choose two coins with order unimportant, because ${5\choose 2} = 5!/2!3! = 120/(2)(6) = 10$.

Comment: It might also be useful to note that it is referred to commonly as the Binomial Coefficient

Comment: And we might add that the way to pronounce $\binom{n}{r}$ is "$n$ choose $r$".